# Mouse events not working as they should in functions

Tags: c++, function, mouseevent

I am displaying a card stack and need to know the exact pinpoints of the pixels so I mapped out a function that should return whatever LMB location was at pressed time. The issue with this is that for some reason I can no longer see the cards.

I tried making the function a class member of Game, but then the mouse logic doesn't work at all. I still had MyMouse M; declared but its like the code was just ignored completely. I know how to overload functions and yet this just seems to defy logic.

Function for MouseLogic();

```
void MouseLogic() {
Game G;
Coordinates C;
MyMouse M;

G.PrintLL(10, 25, G.start_user);
G.PrintLL(10, 10, G.start_cpu);

while (1) {
    M.ReadMouseInput();
    switch (M.InputRecord.EventType)
    {
    case MOUSE_EVENT: // mouse input 
        if (M.InputRecord.Event.MouseEvent.dwButtonState == FROM_LEFT_1ST_BUTTON_PRESSED)
        {
            int x = M.InputRecord.Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.X;
            int y = M.InputRecord.Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.Y;

            cout << GetCardNumber(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Function for GetCardNumber

```
  int GetCardNumber(int x, int y)
{
    if ((x >= 10 && x <= 23) && (y >= 10 && y <= 25))
        return 1;
    else if ((x >= 41 && x <= 54) && (y >= 10 && y <= 25))
        return 2;
    else if ((x >= 72 && x <= 85) && (y >= 10 && y <= 25))
        return 3;
    else if ((x >= 45 && x <= 60) && (y >= 10 && y <= 25))
        return 4;
    else if ((x >= 78 && x <= 91) && (y >= 10 && y <= 25))
        return 5;
    else if ((x >= 10 && x <= 23) && (y >= 25 && y <= 40))
        return 6;
    else if ((x >= 41 && x <= 54) && (y >= 25 && y <= 40))
        return 7;
    else if ((x >= 72 && x <= 85) && (y >= 25 && y <= 40))
        return 8;
    else if ((x >= 45 && x <= 60) && (y >= 25 && y <= 40))
        return 9;
    else if ((x >= 78 && x <= 91) && (y >= 25 && y <= 40))
        return 10;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work for anyone wondering! I just had to pass the class as an argument for some reason. Would still love an explanation for the logic behind this.

```
void MouseLogic(Game G) {
    Coordinates C;
    MyMouse M;

    G.PrintLL(10, 25, G.start_user);
    G.PrintLL(10, 10, G.start_cpu);

    while (1) {
        M.ReadMouseInput();
        switch (M.InputRecord.EventType)
        {
        case MOUSE_EVENT: // mouse input 
            if (M.InputRecord.Event.MouseEvent.dwButtonState == FROM_LEFT_1ST_BUTTON_PRESSED)
            {
                int x = M.InputRecord.Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.X;
                int y = M.InputRecord.Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.Y;

                cout << GetCardNumber(x, y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).